# Error while installing Visual Page Editor in JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am trying to install Visual Page Editor in JBoss Developer Studio (basically customized Eclipse Luna). As per instrauctions I should: `Visual Page Editor has experimental support for Windows 64-bit. Follow the link below to get details on how to install. Until then you can click on the Source tab to hide this error/info message.` so I did it and added "http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/integration/luna/core/xulrunner/xulrunner-1.9.2_win64-2014-08-22_09-55-58-B4/" through Install New Software, but it fails with error:

```
org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.XulRunnerBundleNotFoundException: Bundle org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_64 is not found.
    at org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.browser.XulRunnerBrowser.getXulRunnerPath(XulRunnerBrowser.java:233)
    at org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.browser.XulRunnerBrowser.<init>(XulRunnerBrowser.java:117)
    at org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.editor.XulRunnerEditor.<init>(XulRunnerEditor.java:128)
    at org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.mozilla.XulRunnerEditor2.<init>(XulRunnerEditor2.java:23)
    at org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.mozilla.MozillaEditor.createPartControl(MozillaEditor.java:594)
    at org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.VpeEditorPart.createVisualEditor(VpeEditorPart.java:813)  ... etc
```

**Quite interesting and confusing, same software (plugin) can be installed without problems via same method (Install New Software option) in ordinary Eclipse Luna EE.**

What gone wrong here and how should I resolve this issue with JBoss Developer Studio and install that plugin (JBoss Tools - xulrunner) in order to be able to use Visual Page Editor http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/faq/visualeditor.html ?

Answer (score 2):

I got it. You need to install `xulrunner` for `eclipse luna` from [here](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/integration/luna/core/xulrunner/xulrunner-1.9.2_win64-2014-08-22_09-55-58-B4/) 
I installed it in eclipse "`Kepler Service Release 2`" and it works fine for me

Comment: this should be the accepted answer for Luna and Kepler

Answer (score -1):

If you are using 64 bit windows with Eclipse Luna and JBOSS Tools then you need to download the xulrunner components by following the steps below:

1) 
[enter image description here][1]

2) Eclipse > Help > Install New Software

[enter image description here][2]

3) Add URL below to

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/integration/luna/core/xulrunner/xulrunner-1.9.2_win64-2014-08-22_09-55-58-B4/

[enter image description here][3]

4) Select xulrunner support and install all and this will solve visual editor error on Eclipse Luna

Restart Eclipse

Visual Editor will work.